# Error "oldIndex must be a valid index in the Children collection" when opening a source file in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I occasionally receive a modal popup window in Visual Studio 2012 with the following error:

> oldIndex must be a valid index in the Children collection
>
> Parameter name: oldIndex
>
> Actual value was -1.

The only reference of that error I found was in [this Resharper bugtracking thread](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-334572), but I don't think it is related to Resharper. In my case it seems to happen after I start debugging and for some reason the debugger suddenly doesn't manage to find the source files, not even when "stepping into". Trying to open them manually fails, during debugging without any message, after I stop debugging, the above message appears.

I have not (yet) been able to reproduce this consistently. Still, I figured it warranted a question on SO in case others have seen it and/or have a possible solution. If I can reproduce it consistently, I should probably file a bugreport at Microsoft Connect.

Once this error pops up, soon no files at all open anymore, all raising the same error. Only after I restart Visual Studio, I can continue normal operation.

Comment: It's not related to ReSharper. I don't have it installed for VS 2012 and this error still occasionally pops up. Most commonly it happens when you open a file, set debug breakpoint and attach to a process. The file will dissapear and no way to open it again (ctrl + Tab, open from solution browser). Stop debugging session and double click the file that got hidden - the error message pops up.

Comment: @AlesPotocnikHahonina: looks like a bug by Microsoft in VS itself then.

Comment: Just came across another strange error. I had two instances of VS 2012 open and both had part of the same projects loaded. I added a new attribute to one of the shared projects with (AttributeUssage = class). I then attempted to add a new controller to an MVC project in the same instance of VS and it popped up an error message, saying it could not load the class I just added. Guess it needs it for "Add Controller" dialog but it should be able to load it. So, my point is there are plenty of other bugs in VS itself rather than R#.

Comment: I remember getting that error a lot after debugging too, haven't seen it once since upgrading to VS 2013. So upgrade, and move on to a new set of debugger bugs :)

Comment: if the bug is occuring often, you can try to debug VS with an other instance of VS. When the bug occure, the callstack may be informative. Typically i used to do that for WPF designer bug, in your case i don't know, but i would try it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2009/06/08/9711306.aspx

Comment: @Bombinosh: yes, the problem is that it is not an exception, and it is easy to break on an exception, but not on a modal popup like this (it also makes it next to impossible to attach at the moment the error occurs). The error appears occasionally, and recently I haven't seen it anymore (VS2010/12/13). It is possible that MS, or R# has fixed the bug.

Comment: Perhaps you should make an answer: Restart Visual Studio as a workaround and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the suggestion of [ekenman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310146/ekenman), I add the only answer so far that helped, but it is not a *real* answer in my opinion. If a proper answer comes up, I will accept that instead.

Solution: restart Visual Studio :(.

Comment: In my case the problem is quite persistent. It doesn't help even after a restart :(

Comment: BTW, I'm back after restarting the windows and it works :) It's weird but if restart VS doesn't help, restart Windows! Lol!!

Comment: By restarting VS problem solved. But still there is question why this problem occured? what exactly happened?

Comment: @onkar, I don't know, and considering this is a pretty old VS version, I doubt it'll get much attention now from Microsoft. Unless you're saying it still happens with the latest editions?

Comment: Still happens in VS 2019!!

Comment: @DylanNicholson, do you have a repro?

Comment: Nope sorry, but I had to shut down and restart VS in order to open a particular source file.

Comment: It still _sometimes_ happens in VS2019. :( But closing _all_ my VS instances and starting over worked.

Comment: Happened in VS 2019 professional when I did a git checkout from CLI. Restarting fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Jetbrains Resharper worked for me in VS 2013 Professional.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps that helps others. Though almost nobody uses VS 2013 anymore, it's now VS 2019 (and it's free).